# How would I fill a table from highchart data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

If I have a chart and a table like below and I want to pass the chart data into the table cells. How would I pass it?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
},
series: {
    data: [100,200, 300],
        },   
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<table id="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Column</th>
      <th>Second Column</th>
      <th>Third Column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like you have not imported the highcharts library. Do this by adding <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

Comment: Can you please replicate your issue on jsfiddle or statckoverflow run code snippet so that we can help you better way

Comment: @ShahnawazAlam Yes I added this library.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar the code is much large in size.

Comment: @CodingFriend, You can include required JS files and the code for which you need solution. This will help others to understand the problem and help you better

Comment: Highcharts has a demo where you can use data from an HTML table to power the chart: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/. It's basically what you want, but in reverse. Depending on what you're looking to do, that could be useful for you.

Comment: @MikeZavarello Yeah, your suggestion is helpful but I cant reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic way you can use Highcharts and jQuery to fill the cells of your HTML table with the data from your chart.

First, we want to set a placeholder row in your table where we'll fill in the data. I've given this row the ID of `RowToFill` so we can refer to it in the Javascript.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

<table id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Column</th>
            <th>Second Column</th>
            <th>Third Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="RowToFill">
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Next, we'll go through the chart's data and add table cells to our placeholder row using the jQuery `append()` function.

**Javascript:**

```
/* set the chart to a variable so you can get to the data later */
var thisChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['A', 'B', 'C']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [100,200,300]
    }]
});

/* go through each item in the chart series */
$(thisChart.series[0].data).each(function( index ) {
    /* add a table cell to the row where it should go */
    $('#RowToFill').append('<td>' + this.y + '</td>');
});
```

Here's a working fiddle with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/5ad8fgzp/

To make this more flexible, you could modify this function to first run through a list of x-axis categories to create the table header row. This would make the number of cells in your table body row match the number of data points in your chart.

I hope this is helpful for you.